# Como desabilitar a mensagem de merge no git pull?

Tags: git

Sempre que aciono o `git pull`, o git abre o editor de texto solicitando uma mensagem para o commit de merge. Porém esta mensagem já é previamente carregada (como no exemplo abaixo) e eu simplesmente salvo e fecho a janela para finalizar o procedimento.

```
Merge branch 'dev' of https://bitbucket.org/myproject into dev
```

No caso do meu time, não faz sentido personalizar esta mensagem.
Como faço então para desabilitar esta solicitação?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O comando que você quer é

```
$ git pull --no-edit
```

Pessoalmente eu prefiro usar `--no-edit` quando faço `git merge` e não em `git pull` porque pra mim é importante saber quando o `HEAD` do meu repositório local não corresponde ao remoto.

Answer (score 2):

Essa mensagem só acontece quando você faz um `git pull` e o repositório remoto recebeu novos *commits*.

Como o git precisa conciliar os novos *commits* com o seu *commit* local, por padrão ele irá fazer um [*3-way merge*](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-merge) e criar esse novo *commit* de *merge*, consequentemente mostrando essa mensagem caso você queira modificá-la.

Uma forma de evitar isso é utilizar o `git pull --rebase`, assim ele irá recriar os *commits* locais a partir de um novo *parent* (no caso o HEAD remoto) e não terá esse problema com o *commit* de *merge*.

Para mais detalhes veja algumas referencias:

- [Git merge](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-merge)
- [Básico de Branch e Merge](https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Ramifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-Branching-no-Git-B%C3%A1sico-de-Branch-e-Merge)

Comment: Eu não gostaria de mudar os commits. Somente quero saber se é possível não solicitar a personalização da mensagem de commit, usando sempre a mensagem padrão mesmo.

Comment: Essa estratégia funciona, mas ela está constantemente reescrevendo a história do branch em cada local. Pra alguns flows isso funciona melhor que pra outros, a depender de como os desenvolvedores trabalham e talvez do tamanho das mudanças em cada local.

Answer (score 0):

Você tem interesse em realizar o commit imediatamente? caso seja esse o seu objetivo dependendo do gerenciador que você usa no caso do gitkraken ou sourcetree você tem a possibilidade de marcar para commitar merge imediatamente após o merge(caso não tenha conflito) aí não precisa escrever nem fazer nada só enviar pra origin, apenas dar o push. A mensagem é só em caso de interesse em personalizar eu acredito.

Comment: Para uso trivial do dia-a-dia prefiro usar o terminal mesmo. Busco uma solução junto ao terminal.